# Why doesn't this typecheck?

Tags: debugging, haskell, types, typechecking, pointfree

`compress xs@(_:_:_) = (ifte <$> ((==) <$> head <*> head.tail) <$> ((compress.).(:) <$> head <*> tail.tail) <*> ((:) <$> head <*> compress.tail) ) xs`

Results in a type error, but I can't see why. It should be equivalent to

`compress xs@(_:_:_) = (ifte (((==) <$> head <*> head.tail) xs) (((compress.).(:) <$> head <*> tail.tail) xs) (((:) <$> head <*> compress.tail) xs))`

, which doesn't.

note: `ifte = (\ x y z -> if x then y else z)` , `<$>` and `<*>` are from `Control.Applicative` .

**EDIT:** The error is:

```
Couldn't match expected type `[a]' with actual type `[a] -> [a]'
    In the expression:
        (ifte <$> ((==) <$> head <*> head . tail)
     <$>
       ((compress .) . (:) <$> head <*> tail . tail)
   <*>
     ((:) <$> head <*> compress . tail))
      $ xs
    In an equation for `compress':
        compress xs@(_ : _ : _)
          = (ifte <$> ((==) <$> head <*> head . tail)
         <$>
           ((compress .) . (:) <$> head <*> tail . tail)
       <*>
         ((:) <$> head <*> compress . tail))
          $ xs
```

I encountered this problem trying to write a pointfree solution to problem 8 of the [Ninety-Nine Haskell Problems](http://haskell.org/haskellwiki/H-99%3a_Ninety-Nine_Haskell_Problems). I was trying to do it by modifying the pointful solution I had written, which was

```
compress::Eq a => [a]->[a]
compress [] = []
compress (x:[]) = (x:[])
compress (x:y:xs) = ifte ((==) x y) (compress (x:xs)) (x:(compress (y:xs)))
```

Comment: Could you please paste the type error and maybe a less pointed version of the code?

Comment: Sorry. You give us a big pile of both pointless and opaque code to decipher, whithout even mentioning the purpose of the code or any details such as the exact error you get. How are we supposed to help you? -1.

Comment: -1. This is a typical situation to take a glass of water and think what on earth one really are doing.

Comment: I think OP was experimenting with pointfree (which usually gives such applicative mess) and attempted to get rid of if-then-else with ifte.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, indent. Second, consider using some variables.

Even with more sensible formatting, you can see that it's

```
compress =
  ifte <$> ((==) <$> head <*> head.tail)
       <$> ((compress.).(:) <$> head <*> tail.tail)
       <*> ((:) <$> head <*> compress.tail)
```

when it should be

```
compress =
  ifte <$> ((==) <$> head <*> head.tail)
       <*> ((compress.).(:) <$> head <*> tail.tail)
       <*> ((:) <$> head <*> compress.tail)
```

Third, even if you must be inscrutable, how about

```
compress (x:r@(y:_)) = ifte (x==y) id (x:) $ compress r
```

or, point free

```
compress = map fst . filter (uncurry (/=)) . (zip <$> id <*> tail)
```

Comment: or even `compress = map head . group`

Comment: Also your last pointfree code removes last element of the list, perhaps it's not what OP wanted.

Comment: Is it different? The original code is missing a base case for finite lists, so I didn't worry about tails.

Comment: Brandon: Base case for finite lists can be easily added with extra equations for empty and singleton lists (in fact OP added them in question), but the last version is not that easy to modify.

Answer (score 5):

Here's your code written in  a little more readable way

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}
import Control.Applicative

u = ((==) <$> head <*> head.tail)
v = ((compress.).(:) <$> head <*> tail.tail)
w = ((:) <$> head <*> compress.tail)

ifte = (\ x y z -> if x then y else z) 

--compress xs@(_:_:_) = (ifte <$> u <$> v <*> w) xs
compress xs@(_:_:_) = (ifte (u xs) (v xs) (w xs))
```

I hope you see now the mistake - correct version is

```
--compress xs@(_:_:_) = (ifte <$> u <*> v <*> w) xs
```

Comment: +1 for taking a horrible question and making something useful out of it

Answer (score 2):

This is very similar to what has already been said, but indulge me for a moment, and allow me to preach to you the value of types.

```
import Control.Applicative

ifte :: Bool -> a -> a -> a
ifte b t f = if b then t else f

compress :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
-- compress = ifte <$> cond <$> t <*> f
-- We will leave compress undefined so we can load this into ghci.
-- After some trial and error it is clear that this is the part
-- that doesn't type check
compress = undefined

cond :: Eq a => [a] -> Bool
cond = (==) <$> head <*> head . tail

t :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
t = (compress .) . (:) <$> head <*> tail . tail

f :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
f = (:) <$> head <*> compress . tail
```

Here I've split it out, and as Brandon mentioned, at this point you should see that the error lies in using `<$>` where `<*>` should be. You will get comfortable with that concept as you keep learning applicative style, where your expressions typically have a single `<$>` followed an arbitrary # of `<*>`:

```
f <$> a <*> b <*> c <*> d <*> ...
```

Ignoring that insight, though, I've given each subexpression here a type and a TLD, temporarily. This lets me load the file into ghci and play around a bit.

```
ghci> :t ifte <$> cond <$> t <*> f
... Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
```

WTF??? It is type sound??? It was supposed to give an error, but apparently this expression is a-OK. Or is it? Notice this type signature **doesn't match the one we want for `compress`**.

```
ghci> :t compress
... Eq a => [a] -> [a]
```

The sub-expressions match the type signatures that we expect them to, as evidenced by the compiler not vomiting on us. Since that is the case, the problem is clearly in the way we combine them. So what are the pieces we want to combine here? Ignoring the Eq constraints:

```
ifte :: Bool -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]
cond :: [a] -> Bool
t    :: [a] -> [a]
f    :: [a] -> [a]

-- desired result
     :: [a] -> [a]
```

Here I've made the trivial specialization of `ifte` for `[a]` instead of any `a`. The relationship is clear: the output type of `cond`, `t`, and `f` match the input types of `ifte`. We just need to feed all three of those expressions the same `[a]`. Recognizing that `(input ->)` is applicative, we generalize:

```
arg1 :: (a -> b -> c -> d)
arg2 :: f a
arg3 :: f b
arg4 :: f c
res  :: f d

-- for our case,
-- f = ([a] ->)
-- a = Bool
-- b = [a]
-- c = [a]
-- d = [a]
```

Stop...Hoogle time! [Hoogling `(a -> b -> c -> d) -> f a -> f b -> f c -> f d`](http://haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28a+-%3E+b+-%3E+c+-%3E+d%29+-%3E+f+a+-%3E+f+b+-%3E+f+c+-%3E+f+d), we immediately find `liftA3`, which is, not surprisingly defined:

```
liftA3 f a b c = f <$> a <*> b <*> c
```